# Parent read from pipe - what condition

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I' ve got a program, where children send to pipe messages: "hello", and "goodbay". They send hello and then sleep random time in seconds. After waking up, they send "goodbay".
My problem is, I guess, that parent read from pipe only once and then finish work. I think it must check pipe ever and again... Can anyone help me?

My code:

```
void child_work(int pipe)
{
    int tt;
    char mb[PIPE_BUF];

    snprintf(mb,PIPE_BUF,"Pid[%d]: Hello\n",getpid());
    if (-1 == TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY (write (pipe, mb, strlen(mb))))ERR ("write");

    for(tt=5;tt>0;tt=sleep(tt));

    snprintf(mb,PIPE_BUF,"Pid[%d]: Goodbye\n",getpid());
    if (TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY (write (pipe, mb, (strlen(mb)+1)))<0)ERR ("write");
    kill(getpid(),SIGTERM);
}

void parent_work(int pipe)
{
    char buffer[PIPE_BUF];  
    int result;

   do
{
    result=TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(read(pipe, buffer,sizeof(buffer)));
    if(result<0)ERR("read");
    if(result>0)printf("%s\n", buffer); 

}while(result>0);

    while((TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(wait(NULL)))>0);
}
```

Comment: the parent is reading from the pipe in a loop. That should be enough.

Comment: the code shouldn't compile. There is dangling `while(..wait..`

Comment: It's waiting for end of children process. It can be removed. 
I think, the problem is that the buffer is not cleaned and parent is reading even old messages from pipe..

Comment: the issue is that you do not show the code that is actually executed. The code with `read` in the question prints `buffer` once. Does it repeat messages if you remove `TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY` around `write()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buffer` that is set in `while(..read(..buffer..)` is overwritten on the next iteration of the loop by `result = read(..buffer..`.

Comment: I change on result=TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(read(pipe, buffer,PIPE_BUF)) ; and ...while(result>0) but now the same messages are read from pipe by parent couple times...

Comment: [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22532787/edit) with the new code